# how to add timout while scp the file to remote server and if no privilege to sudo via expect script

Tags: shell, expect

I want to add timeouts if there is no privilege on /tmp folder while scp the file and if there is  no sudo privilege while executing the sudo command in below script.Could you please suggest

```
spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    /tmp/rem_script.sh $env(user_name)@$env(first_db_node_ip):/tmp
expect "password:"
send -- "$env(rem_password)\r"
expect eof

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $env(user_name)@$env(first_db_node_ip)
expect "password:"
send -- "$env(rem_password)\r"

expect -ex $
send "PS1=UGLY-PROMPT'# '\r"
expect "UGLY-PROMPT# "

send "sudo chmod 777 /tmp/rem_script.sh\r"
expect {
  "password:" {
    send -- "$env(rem_password)\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  "UGLY-PROMPT# " {}
}

send "sudo sh /tmp/rem_script.sh $env(asrm_name) $env(com_str)\r"
expect {
  "password:" {
    send -- "$env(rem_password)\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  -timeout 60 "UGLY-PROMPT# " {}
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a "timeout" pattern if you want to do something on the timeout rather than just stop waiting for the listed patterns.  Something like the following:

```
send "sudo sh /tmp/rem_script.sh $env(asrm_name) $env(com_str)\r"
expect { 
    -timeout 60
    "password:" {
        send -- "$env(rem_password)\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    timeout { send_user "timed out!" } 
    "UGLY-PROMPT# " {}
}
```

Or whatever you want to do when waiting for the other patterns times out.

You may also want to add patterns specifically looking for the error messages if you don't have the sudo or other priviledges that you expect to have.

Comment: Hi Tim,the timeout you have added will effective for entire script to run? or only the time for expecting password?.what will happen if the script takes more than 60 s to complete.In that case it will terminate in between ?Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: The timeout is only for the single expect statement waiting for the response from the "sudo sh" command.    In this case, if the expected patterns are not seen within 60 seconds the "send_user" command will send the text "timed out!" to the user output.  If you want the script to terminate you'd need to put the exit command into that block.

I don't know of a way to have a global timeout block -- I've never felt the need to do that and I don't spot anything looking at the documentation.

Comment: Edited answer to correct my mistake pointed out in the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following code in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41912268/900078) does **NOT** work:

```
expect -timeout 60 {
    "password:" {
        send -- "$env(rem_password)\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    timeout { send_user "timed out!" } 
    "UGLY-PROMPT# " {}
}
```

Instead we have to put the `-timeout N` in the `expect {}` block. See following example:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat foo.exp
proc expect_prompt {} {
    global spawn_id
    expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+(#|\$)}
}

spawn bash --norc --noprofile

expect -timeout 2 {
    not-found {}
    timeout {
        send_user ">>> you should never see this.\n"
    }
}

expect {
    -timeout 2 not-found {}
    timeout {
        send_user ">>> instead, you would see this.\n"
    }
}

expect_prompt
send "exit\r"
expect eof
[STEP 102] $ expect foo.exp
spawn bash --norc --noprofile
bash-4.4$ >>> instead, you would see this.
exit
exit
[STEP 103] $
```